# Can we add a new Mobile Number as well as Attribute value via Mobile Connect API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

We have a pretty simple form right now that collects a Mobile Number and fires off initial messages via QueueMO. However, we now want to collect ZipCode and append that to the mobile connect subscriber. I believe QueueMO is limited to collecting the phone number only.

I'm having difficulty finding other calls that would suffice for updating the contact. Is there a way to accomplish this via the API?

Answer (score 1):

Still in testing on this one, but think we may have found a workaround here.

The subscription process is actually a double-opt in, so we needed a way to capture a value from the online form and carry it through to confirmation. Here is how we are going about it:

1. Use QueueMO to simulate the Keyword + an additional noun for zipcode. (IE: "SUBSCRIBE 50212").
2. Use AmpScript in the outbound response to parse the zipcode. If it is present we store that and the mobilenumber from the conversation to a data extension. We display a generic message. The zipcode storage takes place in the background.
3. If the recipient replies "Y" we use AmpScript to receive the information from the data extension by use of the current MOBILE_NUMBER.
4. We again use Ampscript to Upsert a Contact to "mobile" with the attribute and value for zipcode. We can presumably collect other attributes this same way by indexing them appropriately in the QueueMO message override.

Hopefully this will help others who need to capture this information without a subsequent Info Gather text type in Mobile Connect.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey Justin - where you able to verify this functionality?